# If $n, d \in \mathbb{N}$ are such that $d < n$, show that $n = c_0 + c_1d+ \cdots + c_kd^k$ with each $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $0 \leq c_i < d$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, integers, euclidean-algorithm

I am trying to prove one of the early questions in Serge Lang's Undergraduate Algebra textbook (Question 1 on Section 1.5) and I am not sure if I have proven it correctly.

> 1. Let $n, d \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume $1 < d < n$. Show that $n$ can be written in the form
>    \begin{equation*}
>        n = c_0 + c_1 d + \cdots + c_kd^k
>    \end{equation*}
>    with integers $c_i$ such that $0 \leq c_i < d$ and that these integers are uniquely determined. [Hint: For the existence, write $n = qd + c_0$ by the Euclidean algorithm, and then use induction. For the uniqueness, use induction, assuming $c_0, c_1,..., c_r$ are uniquely determined; show that $c_{r + 1}$ is then uniquely determined.]

Here is my attempt:

**Proof:** We first prove the existence of such representation. We can first apply the Euclidean algorithm as by the hint of the form
\begin{equation*}
n = qd + c_0
\end{equation*}
To use induction, assume the base case when $k = 0$. Then we have $q = 0$ so that $n = c_0$. For $k = 1$, we have $q = c_1$ so that $n = c_0 + c_1d$. For $k = 2$, we have $q = c_1 + c_2d$ so that $n = (c_1 + c_2d)d + c_0 = c_0 + c_1d + c_2d^2$. Now let us assume that for $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, that
\begin{equation*}
q = c_1 + c_2d + \cdots + c_kd^{k - 1}
\end{equation*}
is such that
\begin{equation*}
n = c_0 + c_1d + c_2d^2 + \cdots + c_kd^k
\end{equation*}
Then for $k + 1$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
q = c_1 + c_2d + \cdots + c_{k + 1}d^k
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
n = qd + c_0 = (c_1 + c_2d + \cdots + c_{k + 1}d^k)d + c_0 = c_0 + c_1d + c_2d^2 + \cdots + c_{k + 1}d^{k + 1}
\end{equation*}
as required.

My question: (1) Am I showing the steps correctly for the representation for $n$, and (2) I am not sure how to show that each of the integer coefficients are uniquely determined, but I am thinking that for each $i$, each of the coefficients can be such that $c_i = c_i'$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $k$ can't be zero since $n>d.$ But it is weird that Lang includes the entirely unnecessary condition $n >d,$ and leaves out the condition $d>1.$ Are you aware of the colloquial way to write this statement: That every natural number $n$ can be written uniquely in base $d?$

Comment: In any event, when $d=1,$ this theorem is not true.

Comment: The general approach would be strong induction on $n.$ Once you write $n=dq+r,$ you apply the induction hypothesis to $q.$

Comment: Sorry @ThomasAndrews, I forgot to include that condition. But you're right, should be $1 < d < n$.

Comment: You shouldn't need $d<n,$ though. It is easier to prove without that condition.

Comment: It is also not true that the representation is unique. For example, when $n=34$ and $d=10,$ $$n=4 d^0+3 d^1=4 d^0+3d^1+0d^2$$ However, if you add the condition $c_k\neq 0,$ the representation is unique.